# How to create custom controls with properties

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to create a custom control with properties.

This is my custom control:

```
public class ExpandableStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public String Title{get;set;}

    public ContentView View { set; get; }

    public String Image{set;get;}


    public ExpandableStackLayout(string title, string image, ContentView view)
    {
        Title = title;
        Image = image;
        View = view;
    }
}
```

But when I try used it in xaml says : "No default constructor find" and if i create the default constructor call this and not call constructor with parameters.

This is my xaml:

```
<control:ExpandableStackLayout Title="Title" Image="imag.png">
            <control:ExpandableStackLayout.View>
                <ContentView>
                    <OtherView/>
                </ContentView>
            </control:ExpandableStackLayout.View>
        </control:ExpandableStackLayout>
```

***UPDATE***

I tried with your tips and i have others problems:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Title",
        returnType: typeof(String),
        declaringType: typeof(String),
        defaultValue: String.Empty);

    public String Title
    {
        get => (String)GetValue(TitleProperty); 
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value); 
    }

    public ContentView View { set; get; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Image",
        returnType: typeof(String),
        declaringType: typeof(String),
        defaultValue: string.Empty);

    public String Image
    {
        get => (String)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }

    public ExpandableStackLayout()
    {
        //Do somethings whith parameters but are null
        usemyParameters();
    }
```

Comment: The declaringType should be `typeof(ExpandableStackLayout)`

Comment: typeof of a propertie?? Could you show me a little example over where put it?

Comment: Sure: `public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Image",
        returnType: typeof(String),
        declaringType: typeof(ExpandableStackLayout),
        defaultValue: string.Empty);`. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/)

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to create constructor. Here is the solution how to implement Title and Image properties.

```
public class ExpandableStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<ExpandableStackLayout, string>(p => p.Title, string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<ExpandableStackLayout, string>(p => p.Image, string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Image
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I don't know what you want to achieve with the View. As a start I recommend you to study [these controls](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls) and [Stacklayout implementation](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/StackLayout.cs).

Comment: I want a StackLayout with an other view inside. I want create a control with a special features and a view . This view can be stackLayout or grid or etc... . I want create reusable control.

Comment: @MiguelAngelMuñoz I don't get it. If you want to have a View inside ExpandableStackLayout move your code there.

Answer (score 4):

For binding variables from .xaml to .cs code you should use Bindable Properties.

Your .cs file should look like this

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ExpandableStackLayout  : StackLayout
{
    public ExpandableStackLayout ()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(ExpandableStackLayout), string.Empty);

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties of custom views are not supposed to be set via the constructor. The way to go to implement a property of a custom view are [Bindable Properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/).

Basically you have to create two things to create a fully fledged bindable property:

- A `public static BindableProperty`
- A C# property getting and setting the `BindableProperty` in a explicit getter and setter respectively

I will explain it, using the `Title` property as an example. First of all create a simple auto property (the C# property and the `BindableProperty` are interdependent)

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

In the second step you create the `BindableProperty`

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty 
    = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(ExpandableStackLayout));
```

`TitleProperty` is a naming convention to access the property as `Title` from your XAML.

The last step is to access the value of `TitleProperty` via `Title`

```
public string Title
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
    set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
}
```

this simplifies accessing `TitleProperty`.